# Jquery animation 'hover' lost to delete item

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am trying to remove an item from a list without losing the animation 'hover':
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LV9Eg/2/)

**Code**

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.parent').hover(function() {

        $('.child').css({
            "width": "320px",
            "height": "300px"
        });
        $(this).find('.child').dequeue().stop().slideToggle("fast");

    });

    $(".binda").click(function() {
        $(this).remove()
    });

});​
```

Comment: but, no after to delete item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/pYa87/

API:

- `.mouseover` - http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/
- `.slideUp` - http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.parent').mouseover(function() {

        $('.child').css({
            "width": "320px",
            "height": "300px"
        });
        $(this).find('.child').dequeue().stop().slideDown("fast");

    }).mouseout(function() {

        $(this).find('.child').dequeue().stop().slideUp("fast");
    });

    $(".binda").click(function() {
        $(this).remove()
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach makes sense, but unfortunately won't work. I fixed up the fiddle and implemented what you can do based off what I think you're trying to do.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.parent').hover(function() {
        $('.child').stop().slideDown('fast');
    }, function() {
        $('.child').stop().slideUp('fast');
    });

    $('.binda').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});​
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AustinBrunkhorst/LV9Eg/3/)**